# Command button to import text to textview from edittext using Scanner?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

ok so i what to develop an application that will take the text from edittext to textview with the click of button this is what i have so far kind of a noob to java

```
package one.two;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class one extends Activity {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner what = new Scanner(System.in);
    what.toString();

}   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all remove the main() method, it's not used by the Android framework. I suggest you read the [Android beginner tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) before you start with your own application.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btn = findViewById(yourButtonId);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText txt = findViewById(yourEditTextId);
        TextView txt1 = findViewById(yourTextViewId);  
        txt.setText( txt.getText().toString() );
    }
});
```

Comment: You need `txt1.setText(txt.getText().toString())`.  You also need to cast all three of your findViewById() calls to the appropriate types.

Comment: ok i have removed the main method but now am getting an error when i type what.toString();

Comment: Why do you have `what.toString()` in there? Do what Flo said and get rid of your `main()` method and what's inside it.  It's not used by Android.  You need to learn the API of the platform and use what you know about Java as supplemental material.  `Scanner` objects are not used in the way you're attempting to use it.

Comment: ok when i put my ids in am getting an error and on the btn.setonclicklistener(new onclicklistener() am getting Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Comment: nevermind about the ids am still getiing Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token